# Disconnecting the data cable without dismounting

Tags: hard-drive, disk-encryption, unmounting

I know that cutting the electrical power to a whole disk (and specifically an encrypted one), without first dismounting it, can damage data.
How about disconnecting only the data cable?  Is that safe?

It is possible to make it safe, how?
Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using Veracrypt to encrypt the disk.

Comment: Why would you do what you describe? What pratical problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Same problems as unplugging the power cable, save perhaps the heads moving somewhere safe (if modern hard drives don't do that automatically no matter what, not sure)

Answer (score 0):

> I know that cutting the electrical power to a whole disk (and specifically an encrypted one), without first dismounting it, can damage data.

Can you cite a reference that explains why an encrypted disk is more susceptible than an ordinary one?

---

> How about disconnecting only the data cable? Is that safe?

The SATA connectors permit hot-plugging, so there's no electrical issue.

The integrated disk controller buffers the command and data as it is received over the SATA interface. Only after the ATA packet has been completely transferred and verified with its CRC, is the actual sector-write operation performed.
There is no simultaneous receive-the-sector-data-over-SATA-while-writing-that-sector.
So there is no need to be concerned about a disconnection directly causing data corruption on the media.

But disconnecting a drive (encrypted or not) *by any means* while that drive has a filesystem that is *still mounted* can lead to an inconsistent filesystem.

---

> It is possible to make it safe, how?

[Journaling filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) have been developed that can tolerate kernel abort/failure, disconnection and power-outage.
However the disk subsystem (which inserts an additional layer of buffering and/or caches) could defeat the robustness of a journaling filesystem.  Some of those issues could be mitigated at the expense of performance.

See [Is a journaling filesystem a good idea with a dm-crypt encrypted drive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/is-a-journaling-filesystem-a-good-idea-with-a-dm-crypt-encrypted-drive)
and
[VeraCrypt with a journaling file system](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Journaling%20File%20Systems).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I think that my question has become moot.  I no longer have a need to do it.

My original idea was to maintain two sets of backup drives.  Only one set would be connected to the computer at any given time.  This was to preserve a backup in the event of ransomeware.

As I indicated in my original question, I know that it is possible to make the disconnection safe for the disk by techniques such as those described by one of you.  I have done such things.  The disks that I use for my external backups are USB drives, and I am not overly familiar with the USB specification, hence my question.

The issue is now moot for two reasons.  First, there are 3 or 4 drives in each backup set.  I realized that plugging and unplugging 8 data cables is inconvenient.  It is easier to attach all of the drives on a backup set to the same power source.  They could then all be disabled by the throw of a single switch.  That is more convenient even though I would shut down my computer and restart.

More importantly, such an approach will not protect me from ransomeware.  I had planned to switch backup drive sets every 2 to 4 days.  I have since been told that ransomeware sometimes waits a month or more before presenting the ransome demand.  Thus, both backup sets could become affected.

It has been suggested that I use network attached storage as a ransomeware protection, but I am not sure that that will work either.

At any rate, thanks to all who replied.